# PHP/Ajax PDF generation timeout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, mpdf

I have a code in PHP/ajax/jquery to create documents with values from database. But when user wants to generate larger number of pdf's and word files, i have a problem with time needed to generate larger number of files.

For every element from array i want to create a pdf or word with data for that row id from mySQL database. 
Generating of files works nice, i used: http://phpword.codeplex.com/   and mPDF.

Generation of 1 file is ~ 2-3 sec. When  user wants to generate 500 records and pack it in .zip i have a problem.

My code looks like this:

On client side i have creation of array and sending it through ajax call:

```
function() {
    var ids = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/generate_pdf.php',
        data: {
            'filename': $("#filename").val(),
            'idPDF': ids.toString()
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        $("#filename").val("");
        $("#message").append("Loading.<br/>");
        $("#message").append(data);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("Error..");
    });
}
```

My generate_pdf.php file looks like this:

```
<?php 
// pdf library
include_once 'pdf/mpdf.php';

// name of zip
$filename=htmlspecialchars($_POST['filename']);

// open a zip
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('../documents/'.$filename.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 

// get id's of rows sent by ajax
if(isset($_POST['idPDF']))
{
    $setid=$_POST['idPDF'];
    $rows=explode(',',$setid);
}
$count=count($rows);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    // id of every row
    $id=$rows[$i]; 

    // query to read data for file creation
    $upit = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?";

    // here i read everything from database using PDO functions

    // then i create html that will be written to pdf
    $html .=' test  ';

    // mpdf
    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
    // define paper
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', array(176,250));
    // some css
    $style = '<style>
    @page {
        margin-left: 10mm; 
        margin-bottom: 0mm;
    }
    </style>
    ';
    // writting to pdf
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($style);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    // defining a name of pdf
    $filenameID = $somevaluefromdatabaseUNIQUE.'-'.$filename;
    $filenameID=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $filenameID);
    $filenameID=str_replace('/', '-', $filenameID);

    // creating pdf
    $mpdf->Output('../documents/'.$filenameID.'.pdf','F');

    // add pdf to zip
    $zip->addFile('../documents/'.$$filenameID.'.pdf', ''.$filenameID.'.pdf');
}

// close the zip
$zip->close();

// returned message via ajax
echo '<a href="documents/'.$filename.'.zip">Download generated pdf's.</a><br/>';

?>
```

Comment: You may have to separate the initial request for documents from the actual serving of documents. One way to do this is with a job queue. The initial request will add an entry into the queue and return an ID or token. In the background, a cron runs every few minutes and checks for new items in the job queue. When it finds one, it generates all the documents for that job and marks the job ready. On the client side, after your initial request, you periodically query the job status, when it is complete you notify the user that their documents are ready (slick: email). Paypal uses this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with requests timing out. Either you could:

1. Tell your php not to have a max time to run scripts, by passing 0 to the following function:

   ```
       set_time_limit(0);
   ```

   http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php
2. Refactor your code so that the client will send 1 ajax request every couple of seconds, and the server always generates 1 PDF each request.
3. Both options above will make the client wait for a very long time. There is nothing you can do about it, things take time. What you can do is improve user's experience in a similar way Google Drive does when you try to upload a very large file, it will notify you (via email for instance) when it's completed the process. You could make your call queue the IDs of the PDF docs to generate, in a database for instance, and then a cron job run through the queue and actually generate it, so that the user will be freed of the "loading" screen. When your (async) process ends, notify the client via email, if available, or any other option that suits your user case.

Comment: Yes, i know for the set_time_limit and i use it. It's a good idea to use cron job, but i can't use it because of the client demands. Thanks for ideas ;)